# null pointer exception when overriding a parameterless method with a field

Tags: scala, oop

I am working through "Programming in Scala" and it says that you can override a parameterless method with a field, ad gives the following example:

```
abstract class Element {
    def contents: Array[String]
    val height: Int = contents.length
    val width: Int = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}

class ArrayElement(conts: Array[String]) extends Element {
    val contents:Array[String] = conts
}

val a = Array("Hello", "mom")
println(a(0))
val x = new ArrayElement(a)
println(x.contents)
println("Hello, " + x.height)
```

However this code produces a null pointer exception for me.  Replacing "val contents:" with "def contents:" works fine.  I can't really understand where the null pointer exception is coming from, if the contents array is indeed being correctly passed.  It seems to be coming from the "val height = contents.length" line, because replacing those with "def height" also runs correctly.  What am I not understanding about this example?

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568049/scala-initialization-order-of-vals

Comment: `def`s, `lazy val`s and early initializers will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about evaluation order in your abstract class.

`val`s are evaluated once at initialization time, whereas `def`s are evaluated every time they are accessed. The NullPointerException happens during initialization time, because `height` accesses `contents` at a time when it hasn't been initialized yet.

As you suggest, turning `height` and `width` into `def`s is one way to prevent the problem.

Comment: Thanks! So does the base class initialization happen before the subclass initialization?

Comment: Yes, the base class is initialized before the subclass