# Scala fails to initialize a val

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception

I have found kind of a weirdness in the following Scala program (sorry to include all the code, but you'll see why I added it all) :

```
object md2html extends App {
    private val DEFAULT_THEME = Themes.AMAZON_LIGHT

    private val VALID_OPTIONS = Set("editorTheme", "logo", "style")
    try {
        // some code 1
    } catch {
        case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace(); exitWithError(t.getMessage)
    }

    // some code 2 (method definitions only)

    private def parseOption(key: String, value: String) = {
        println(key + " " + VALID_OPTIONS)
        if (! Set("theme","editorTheme", "logo", "style").contains(key)) exitWithError(s"$key is not a valid option")   
        if (key == "theme") Themes(value).toMap else Map(key.drop(2) -> value)
    }

    // some code 3 (method definitions only)
}
```

If `VALID_OPTIONS` is defined after one of the `some code...`, it is evaluated to null in `parseOption`. I can see no good reason for that. I truncated the code for clarity, but if some more code is required I'll be happy to add it.

**EDIT :** I looked a bit more into it, and here is what I found.

When extending `App`, the `val` is not initialized with this code

```
object Test extends App {
    printTest()
    def printTest = println(test)
    val test = "test"
}
```

With a regular main method, it works fine :

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      printTest
    }
    def printTest = println(test)
    val test = "test"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala - initialization order of vals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568049/scala-initialization-order-of-vals)

Comment: If you're looking for a more specific reason than Suma and 0__'s "must be the initialization order", you need to post a simple example that's detailed enough so that it can be run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as I have an additional factor : I'm extending `App`

Comment: Oh, right. I've seen this before somewhere. I'd be surprised if there isn't a duplicate question about it. Could you at least add how and when you're calling `parseOption()`?

Comment: @DanGetz I tried to add a relevant minimal code. Mmm wait, it is actually not so relevant

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had overseen that you use `extends App`. This is another pitfall in Scala, unfortunately:

```
object Foo extends App {
  val bar = "bar"
}

Foo.bar            // null!
Foo.main(Array())
Foo.bar            // now initialized
```

The `App` trait defers the object's initialization to the invocation of the `main` method, so all the `val`s are `null` until the `main` method has been called.

**In summary, the `App` trait and `val`s do not mix well.** I have fallen into that trap many times. If you use `App`, avoid `val`s, if you have to use global state, use `lazy val`s instead.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor bodies, and this goes for singleton objects as well, are evaluated strictly top to bottom. This is a common pitfall in Scala, unfortunately, as it becomes relevant where the `val`s are defined if they are referenced in other places of the constructor.

```
object Foo {
  val rab = useBar    // oops, involuntarily referring to uninitialized val 
  val bar = "bar"

  def useBar: String = bar.reverse        
}

Foo   // NPE
```

Of course, in a better world, the Scala compiler would either disallow the above code, re-order the initialization, or at least warn you. But it doesn't...

Comment: Well, `some code 2` is above the first usage of the `val`, so why does it still evaluate to null when I declare it just under the comment ?

Comment: If the NPE goes away when you change the `val` to `lazy val`, I guarantee you that your problem is the order of initialization, and it might simply not occur to the eye at first sight.

Comment: This has definitely something to do with the fact I'm extending `App`. It is related to the order of initialization, of course, but it would not happen with a regular main method (tested)