# Referencing unimplemented members in scala traits/abstract classes

Tags: scala

I have been bitten a number of times by a situation like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
  val implementMe: String

  val upper = implementMe.toUpperCase
}

class MyClass(s: String) extends MyTrait {
  override val implementMe: String = s
}

val c = new MyClass("Hello, World")

println(c.upper)
```

In this example, everything compiles but the last line throws a NullPointerException at runtime, (I assume) because `upper` is computed before `implementMe` is actually defined.

I know I can fix it by changing `upper` to a `def` or a `lazy val` but it seems like this should be caught at compile time rather than runtime.  Am I doing something wrong/is there a way this sort of problem can be detected at compile time?  Is there a reason the compiler allows this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426017/why-does-implement-abstract-method-using-val-and-call-from-superclass-in-val-exp#51426770) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426017/why-does-implement-abstract-method-using-val-and-call-from-superclass-in-val-exp#51426770) answer your question? The first answer does mention the `-Xcheckinit` flag. As you can see, the question reoccurs often enough that I've started to build my own hyperlinked network of nearly-duplicate answers on this topic...

Comment: Here is another very similar question: [Scala initialization order of vals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568049/scala-initialization-order-of-vals).

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm glad I'm not the only one with this issue.  I could not get the compiler flag to throw any error or warning on this but I'll keep playing around.  Ultimately it's not a blocking issue, just annoying

Comment: The flag still does not throw any compile-time errors, but it will crash with a more-or-less precise error message the first time you access uninitialized fields, intstead of letting the `null`s and `0`s escape into some remote corners of your code. The description says it's rather for testing. If one of the answers solves your problem, I'd vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is initialization, as you've stated. As far as I know, there is no way to detect this at compile time. There is a bit of a trick, called early initialization, that allows you to work around this while avoiding `def` or `lazy val` (if that is your goal):

```
class MyClass(s: String) extends { override val implementMe: String = s } with MyTrait
```